# import error when cross importing django/python

Tags: python, django

Hi all can anyone help me with this I am having import error when I do an import I think its all clashing.all was fine till I imported B because I really need to make a ForeignKey to B from A.

a/models.py

```
from b.models import B #there is the problem
Class A():
    ....
    b = models.ForeignKey(B) # I really have to do this
```

b/models.py

```
from c.models import C

Class B():
    ....
    c = models.ForeignKey(C)
```

c/models.py

```
from a.models import A
Class C():
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this (not import model B, just type a string in format "app_name.model_name")

a/models.py

```
Class A():
    ....
    b = models.ForeignKey("b.B")
```

[ForeignKey docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)